# Installing a new package from command line

Tags: arduino

How do I installed the Arduino IDE in Ubuntu from a command line?  I understand that a command line will look for the package on the web repositories and installed in a proper location in the hard drive.  Please correct me if not correct me if the logic is not correct.  Arduino is found in [http://Arduino.cc](https://arduino.cc)

**UPDATE 1:**

I use this command *sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make*
but after installing a lot of files (Don't know where and in which folder)  don't see any Arduino Icon

[image]

Comment: You can install arduino IDE using apt: `sudo apt install arduino` but in repositories is old version of this program so it's better to download it from official website, uncompress it and run `install.sh`

Comment: @Matej consider turning this into an answer

Comment: @Marej   Thank you but don't understand what you mean by repository and how they are set up.

Comment: @JoseEnriqueCalderon Repositories are where Ubuntu stores its standard packages. By the time a package lands in a repository, the creator of the package may already have a new version. This is the case with Arduino. Follow the link provided by Emmet.

Comment: @JoseEnriqueCalderon 1.) Don't post pictures of text, post the actual text. 2.) In your picture, you have truncated all the important bits of the text 3.) Your question is quickly degrading in quality and reaching a state in which we can't answer it.

Comment: Ubuntu-make is not Arduino IDE. Looks like you have not installed Arduino IDE yet,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install arduino IDE using apt:

```
sudo apt install arduino
```

but in repositories is very old version of this program so better is to download arduino IDE from official website [arduino.cc](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software), uncompress it and run `install.sh` which will install program and create icon.

After installation you will have probably problem with uploading code, so run this command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

Then logout and login (or reboot) and try it again.

There is also tutorial for it on website of arduino [arduino IDE installation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux)

Comment: But what is wrong with the installation that I posted?  Why I can not find any files for the Arduino IDE  ( do not care now about current or not current IDE. I just want to follow up with command installations. Please, update your answer.

Comment: @JoseEnriqueCalderon I am not sure if I understand. Which files you can't find?